# Is there any way to see a list of other files that a torrents peers is sharing?

Tags: torrent

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Mods please feel free to move it if feel so

I am downloading a file (an old rare map-history) via torrents. There is a couple of peers who probably have similar interests in history and maps and they might have more maps in their collection which they are currently sharing. Is there any way to see what else are they sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no. That would be really bad for anonymity and wouldn't work logistically with the torrent protocol. The only way you could find out what they are seeding if by cross-checking the IP of the peers you connect to on other similar torrents / on the same website with their ip.